# What happened to the knowledge of VGER?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-trek, star-trek-the-motion-picture

In the first full length Star Trek movie *The Motion Picture*, Commander Decker assumes the role of *The Creator* and directly inputs the final code sequence so VGER can transmit its vast amount of knowledge. When Commander Decker inputs the final code sequence, VGER starts transforming itself, LT Ilea, and Commander Decker into something new. Spock and Bones say they have helped give birth to a new lifeform. My question is, what has happened to Commander Decker, Ilea, and VGER? Where has the intelligence which VGER has amassed over the 300 years gone? To my knowledge, there is no indication in the following movies or in TNG or other TV shows what exactly has happened. Is there anything which tells us?

Comment: Yes, Spock said this. They formed/merged into a new life form, that knowledge and the various entities became something not of this plane of existence together.

Answer (score 4):

The only answer is, it's unknown.  During the course of Star Trek's TV shows and movies, they encountered many life forms and races.  Some, like the Klingons, Vulcans and Romulans, became integral parts of the show and characters from those races were frequently encountered.  Others, such as The Metrons, The Capellans and VGER slipped into obscurity, never to be heard from again within the Trek lore.